# "Cannot set serial info: Device or resource busy" when using setserial to configure the serial port of matrox frame grabber in linux

Tags: linux, serial-port, mapping, matrox

a matrox frame grabbing card was installed in my ubuntu 18.04,and I tried to using blow commands to check the serial port configuration:

[[image: serial port configuration1]

As you can see,the **lspci** output tells grabbing card has

```
IRQ 16 and port e000,
```

and the output of

```
sudo cat /proc/tty/driver/serial
```

has none of record matches the ouptut of **lspci** by **IRQ and IO port**,so I tried to use this command to mapping:

```
sudo setserial  /dev/ttyS2 port 0xe000 irq 16 uart 16550A baud_base 460800 divisor 4
```

but get a result like this:

```
Cannot set serial info: Device or resource busy
```

It seems like the grabbing card has been mapped already,so I assume the one of record 0 or 4 represents the grabbing card
[image: possible card port mapping]

and  tried to run the tests provided by matrox,but none of them works.

Then I unplugin grabbing card from PCI-X slot,and enter into linux,but

```
sudo cat /proc/tty/driver/serial
```

still gives the same output as grabbing card installed,and it seems none of record 0 or 4 represents grabbing card on the contrary,and this is quite confusing.

My first questions are:

1. Must the output of lspci match with one of the records of in /proc.../serial by the IRQ and IO-Port if serial port mapped correctly?
2. If NO,How do I know which serial record in /proc.../serial represents the grabbing card?
   If Yes,since I got 'device busy',How to put grabbing card to idle?

Comment: Why do you think that the *"matrox frame grabbing card"* has a serial port?  Does the product spec confirm the existence of such a serial port?  FYI *"I/O ports"* does not indicate the existence of any serial port(s).

Comment: @sawdust local agency of matrox gives me a doc to map serial port

Comment: What does the *"doc to map serial port"* contain?  What kind of UART is implemented?  What are the register names and port addresses?  Are there register descriptions?  Assuming that the *"I/O port"* addresses are memory mapped (rather than port addresses), you could use the **devmem2** utility to read those registers from the shell.

Comment: Not provided,can you answer my question